# How to capture string before the symbol

Tags: regex, perl

Morning all,
I want to capture the string before the colon:
and then compare the string after the colon
and remove the values which are equal to the values before the colon.

For example:

```
aaa:aaa-bbb-ccc
```

Output:

```
aaa others:bbb,ccc
```

my code below

```
$string = "aaa:aaa-bbb-ccc";
$first =~ /(:.*\)/; //get aaa before the colon
$others =$string=~ s/$first//; remove the same values after colon
```

Can you please help me ?? Thank you..

Comment: `(:.*\)` means **after** not **before**.  Please clarify your question. Since you have two `aaa`; it is a little confusing. And your output is very different form your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s='aaa:aaa-bbb-ccc';
if ($s=~/^([^:]+):/) {
    my $first=$1;
    $s=~s/\Q$1\E://;
    print "$first others:" . join ',', grep { $_ ne $first } split '-', $s;
}
# aaa others:bbb,ccc
```

Comment: ($s=~/^([^:]+):/) is this to access the string before the colon

Comment: @Azhar: Yes. It captures all the characters on the left hand of the first colon in the string.